# Using Stream Result with Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, resulttype

I am attempting to use a Stream Result to return an image from a struts2 application. I seem to be having problem with configuring the action. Here is the configuration:

```
    <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">filename="${filename}"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
```

The problem seem to be the inputName parameter which according to the docs is:

> the name of the InputStream property from the chained action (default = inputStream).

I am not sure what name I should put there. The error I get is:

> Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack.

Has anyone used this before? Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.nabble.com/Struts-2-File-upload-to-store-the-filedata-td14168069.html) which explained that the `InputStream` has to be created by me. It makes sense that I create an `InputStream` from the file that I want the user to download and then pass the Stream to the result. I guess that's my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you have the contentDisposition wrong, it should be:

```
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment; filename="${filename}"</param>
```

(*Chris*)

Answer (score 3):

Inputname defines the  name of the method that outputs the "stream"

public InputStream getInputStream ()
  {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream ( _bytes );
  }