# Import data from database to an excel sheet and displaying the values in a dropdown list using JAVA

Tags: java, struts2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to export data to Excel sheet through JAVA code. At the same time I want to display those data in a dropdown list . For example I have set of fruits saved in a table in DB and i want to display those fruits in a excel dropdown where users can select one of those.

Referring to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293311/java-exporting-data-from-database-to-excel-and-sending-it-to-client-side), now am able to display values in separate columns. Please help me with this.